# .htaccess block IP and Windows OS combination

Tags: .htaccess

I don't know if this is possible, but I would like to block a specific IP from access the site if they are running windows.

I can block OS's in .htaccess and I can block IP's. But how would I do a combination.

Basically if that person access's the site from that IP with a MAC, it should go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of detect the OS using the HTTP User-Agent header, which you can match against using mod_rewrite. See this link for a list: http://www.geekpedia.com/code47_Detect-operating-system-from-user-agent-string.html

You can also match against an IP using mod_rewrite, both via a `RewriteCond`. So something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\ [0-9A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.2\.3\.4$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

If you have other rules, you're going to want that to be the first rule. This checks that if a user agent contains a `Windows X` (where X is a number of letter) *and* the IP is "1.2.3.4", then it returns a 403 forbidden.

Comment: Thank you Jon. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, please change OS name and IP, you want to block

```
RewriteEngine On
#found OS in user agent
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Windows
# any IP you want to add in condtion
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192.168.1.68$
# Access forbidden any url!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

You can found client `OS` in `http_user_agent` string and found anywhere `Windows`, `.*` will also match `Windows`, `Windows ME` or `Window X` etc.
And Other `RewriteCond` will match IP address, 
Both condition will work together then `RewriteRule` to forbidden any url using [`F`] tag, impiles `L` tag for immediate response.